# btn.setAttribute("onclick","myFunction(this.id)"); dosent work?

Tags: javascript, setattribute

I try this code:

```
tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
alert(r);
      var c = 0;
    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
      row.appendChild(cell);
        c++;
    });
      
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");       
    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("نمایش"));                
    btn.setAttribute("id",r);
    btn.setAttribute("class","tablebtn");
    btn.setAttribute("onclick","myFunction(this.id)");
      
      
  var cell1 = document.createElement('td');
  cell1.appendChild(btn);
  row.appendChild(cell1);
      
      
  

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
      r++;
  });
```

but myFunction(this.id) does not work.It worked first. But after some changes it does not work anymore. please guide me. I explored different solutions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding an "onclick" function with setAttribute()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321775/adding-an-onclick-function-with-setattribute)

Answer (score 3):

don't setAttribute for onclick

you can either set the property directly:

```
btn.onclick = function(e) { myFunction(btn.id) }
```

or using `addEventListener`

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) { myFunction(btn.id) });
```

(you can set id directly, too, and use btn.className = 'tablebtn')